# Construct the Dirac measure for $b \in \mathbb{R}$ by Riesz representation theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $b$ be a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}$. Define $\Lambda: C_C(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$, $\Lambda(f)=f(b)$.

(a) Verify that $\Lambda$ is a positive linear functional.

My attempt: We can show $\Lambda$ is a linear functional first. That is, we need to show $\Lambda (f+g) = \Lambda f + \Lambda g$. Reason: RHS = $f(b)+g(b)=(f+g) (b)$ = LHS.

Also, we need to show $\Lambda (\alpha f) = \alpha \Lambda f$. Reason: RHS = $\alpha f(b)=$ LHS.

We also need to show $\Lambda$ has an additional property: it is a *positive* linear functional. This means that $\Lambda f \geq 0$ whenever $f \geq 0$. This is obviously true.

(b) What is the $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathfrak{M}$, as in the Riesz representation theorem?

**I don't know.** By the Riesz representation theorem, this $\mathfrak{M}$ contains all Borel sets. Thus, it contains all open sets and all closed sets in $ \mathbb{R}$. This is all I know about $\mathfrak{M}$.

(c) What is the positive measure, $\mu$, as in the Riesz representation theorem?

My attempt: by the construction in the Riesz representation theorem, for each open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\mu (V)= \sup \{  \Lambda (f): f \prec V  \}$. Recall that any open set  $V \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $V= \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}  (a_j, b_j)$, where $(a_j, b_j) \cap (a_i, b_i) = \emptyset$, $i \ne j$. Then $\mu (V) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \mu (a_j, b_j)$. I consider one of them. Then $\mu (c,d)=\sup \{  \Lambda (f): f \prec (c,d)  \} =\sup \{  f(b): f \prec (c,d)  \}$, where $f \prec (c,d)$ means $f \in C_C(\mathbb{R}), 0 \leq f \leq 1, \text{supp}(f) \subset (c,d)$.

Thus, if $b \in (c,d)$, then  $\mu (c,d)=1$ if we set $f(b)=1$. If $b \notin (c,d)$, then  $\mu (c,d)=0$. Thus, this positive measure, $\mu$, is an indicator function to indicate whether the fixed point $b$ is in the open set. To complete the answer, we also need to consider when the set is not open. But it suffices to discuss the measure of the single point (or endpoint of the open set). $\mu (\{c\})=\inf\{  \mu(V): V \text{open}, c \in V  \}=0$ because we can always find such an open set that does not contain $b$, say $(c-1, c+\frac{b-c}{2})$. Hence, we can conclude that this positive measure, $\mu$, is an indicator function to indicate whether the fixed point $b$ is in any given set.

**What about my answer for part c?**

Comment: I suggest you edit your title with the actual question that you have about the Riesz representation theorem, rather than have a question within a question

Comment: Changed title. Thanks

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_linear_functional): $\Lambda(f)$ is required to be positive only if $f$ itself is positive.

Comment: @FShrike I see. very simple. Should I change in my body text?

Comment: Yes. Questions $b$ and $c$ are more important. I’m afraid I have only ever studied the linear algebraic Riesz representation theorem, so I can no longer help you. Good luck

Comment: Riesz's theorem tells you that there is a unique positive measure $\mu$ such that for every for every $f\in C_c$, $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f\,d\mu=\Lambda(f):=f(b)$. Note that the Dirac measure centered at $b$ is also such that $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f\,d\delta_b=f(b)$ (because $\delta_b(\Bbb{R}\setminus\{b\}):=0$ and $\delta_b(\{b\}):=1$). So, by uniqueness, $\mu=\delta_b$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo What about part b?

Comment: I'm too lazy to look up the precise statement of the Riesz representation theorem, regarding the $\sigma$-algebras (i.e what exactly the $\sigma$-algebra given by RRT is). However, it is clear that the Dirac measure can be defined on the power set of $\Bbb{R}$ (more generally, for any set $X$, if we fix a point $b\in X$, we can define the Dirac measure $\delta_b$ on the full power set of $X$). I wouldn't be surprised if RRT in this special case actually implies that the $\sigma$-algebra is the power set of $\Bbb{R}$, but even if it's not, the Dirac measure can be extended anyway.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Riesz representation theorem claims there exists a $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}$ which contains all Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Mariana yes, I'm aware of that basic version. There's actually a slightly more refined statement of what the $\sigma$-algebra is. The proof I know uses the Caratheodory extension theorem, which gives a (usually) slightly larger $\sigma$-algebra than just all Borel sets. In some special cases, I know (but can't remember where I read it) it is possible to give an even more complete description. Anyway, for your special case, it is obviously possible to extend to the full power set, so there's no need to think so hard about what exactly the theorem says.